# Wireframes extension unload lines on every update

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

I'm using this wireframe extension https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/extensions/Wireframes/Wireframes.js 
which I slightly modified its colors.

If I slightly move the camera, all the lines disappear and since our app constantly get input from the sensor, we end up with the lines always not showing.

[image]

I can't find what is making those lines disappear. How can I make those to always be visible?

It also happens in this example which you can reproduce:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to avoid this issue after my research. Instead of using `impl.scene` and `impl.sceneAfter`, you can add those wireframe geometries into the viewer overlay. Here are the snippets of a workaround:

```
//!-- 1. Add this two line in the `load` function.
if( this.viewer.impl.overlayScenes[this.overlayName] === undefined )
    this.viewer.impl.createOverlayScene( this.overlayName );

//!-- 2. Modified `addWireframes` with overlay functions
function addWireframes(viewer, overlayName, groups) {
    var groupsCount = groups.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < groupsCount; ++i) {
        viewer.impl.addOverlay( overlayName, groups[i] );
    }
    viewer.impl.invalidate(false, true, true);
}

//!-- 3. Modified `revertWireframes` with overlay functions
function revertWireframes(viewer, overlayName, groups) {
    var groupsCount = groups.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < groupsCount; ++i) {
        viewer.impl.removeOverlay( overlayName, groups[i] );
    }
    viewer.impl.invalidate(false, true, true);
}

//!-- 4 Update `impl.invalidate` function calls
viewer.impl.invalidate(false, true, true);

//!-- 5. Update function calls of both `addWireframes` and `revertWireframes`, for example:
addWireframes(this.viewer, this.overlayName, this.groups);
revertWireframes(this.viewer, this.overlayName, this.groups);
```

**P.S. Since this is just a workaround, not the formal solution. You would have to use it at your own risk.**

=== Old Answer

This might caused by the progressive rendering, you can turn it off via `viewer.setProgressiveRendering( false )`. But it will hurt the performance while viewing a large model in the Forge Viewer.

Progressive rendering is the way how the viewer render large models. And it's no way to prevent and be fixed now unfortunately.

Here is what it looks like on my side:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDwNU.jpg

Comment: I noticed that if I add those lines to the `scene` instead of `sceneAfter` then they stay when I move the model. But now there's another problem, they go behind the meshes of the model: https://media.giphy.com/media/xT9IgoZKCeTbnYqZA4/giphy.gif Any ideas on how to make them go to the front of the mesh? Like they are on Phillipe's old wireframe example.

Comment: A workaround for this issue has been provided in the updated answer. Hope it helps.