# Is there a hidden line display mode for the Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I would like to display a plain old black and white hidden line display mode with the Forge Viewer.  Is there a setting or other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `viewer.setSwapBlackAndWhite(true/false)`, see more [here](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/viewer3d/).

**EDIT**

[This other reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960907/wireframes-extension-unload-lines-on-every-update) might help.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.  I need a plain 3D iso view in hidden line display mode where edges are black and parts are pure white, so you only see the outlines of the parts.  I've tried the different Environment and Lighting Selection options, turning on display edges, and getting rid of shadows, but isn't what I need.

Comment: would you have a sample (how it is and what you need)? maybe just an image showing it

Comment: The question is pretty confusing, no one will be able to help you based on that kind of description... are you working with a 2D or a 3D model? You can set color/rendering style with viewer.setThemingColor, see in the help files: http://autode.sk/2yIzRwH